# Am trying to compile my project in visual studio 2015 it is showing "File not found in any active repository" even though the file is in repository

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Visual Studio keeps spamming my output window with the following:

> File not found in any active repository

Am seeing the file in the repository path but while compile my project it is showing `File not found in any active repository` but actually the file is there in repository.

How do I go about fixing this?

It also gives correct path in output window (which is outside of repository)

Answer (score 0):

Try below
 right-click on the untracked files > add Team Explorer > Changes > Untracked Files > Add